# How To Configure Argo-Workflows with SSO with Helm Values File

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argo

I have several requirements for the argo-workflows, we need to deploy Argo-Workflows with the following:

- Metrics Enabled
- SSO Enabled
- Namespaced Enabled
- S3 Backend Artifacts Enabled
- Logging Format Set to JSON
- Ingress Endpoint Enabled
- Works with ALB and WAF
- Runs on AWS EKS

So we had a working configuration and it worked in the past. But for some odd reason it's no longer working and the server is stuck in CrashLoopBackoff.

This is the following `values.yaml` file we use:

```yaml
---
server:
  serviceType: "NodePort"
  authModes:
    - sso
  secure: true
  sso:
    enabled: true
    insecureSkipVerify: true
    clientId:
      key: "client_id"
      name: "argo-server-sso"
    clientSecret:
      key: "client_secret"
      name: "argo-server-sso"
    issuer: "<some_url>"
    redirectUrl: "<some_url>/oauth2/callback"
    sessionExpiry: "1h" #  1 Hour for Session Expiration
  ingress:
    annotations:
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <some_cert_arn>
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/wafv2-acl-arn: <some_waf_arn>
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443"
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: <some_subnet>
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
      external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: <some_url>
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    enabled: "true"
    ingressClassName: "alb"
    hosts:
      - <some_url>
    paths:
      - /*
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
controller:
  logging:
    format: json
  metricsConfig:
    enabled: "true"
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: "true"
    telemetryConfig:
      enabled: "true"
artifactRepositoryRef:
  artifact-repositories:
    annotations:
      workflows.argoproj.io/default-artifact-repository: default
    default:
      s3:
        bucket: <some_bucket>
        endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
        region: us-east-1
        keyFormat: "workflow\
                    /{{workflow.creationTimestamp.Y}}\
                    /{{workflow.creationTimestamp.m}}\
                    /{{workflow.creationTimestamp.d}}\
                    /{{workflow.name}}\
                    /{{pod.name}}"
        useSDKCreds: true
```

The main thing is that I use terraform and/or helm to apply it:

```bash
helm install argo-workflows argo/argo-workflows --version 0.33.1 -n arrgo-workflows
```

I also opened up a GitHub Bug against Argo-Workflows as well:

- https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/12649